# PHP Регулярные выражения Помогите

Tags: php

Есть код

```
$url = "youtube.com/watch?v=ТУТ КАКОЙ ТО ТЕКСТ";
```

С помощью рег.выражения нужно проверить задана ли такая ссылка, вместо "ТУТ КАКОЙ ТО ТЕКСТ" должно быть что угодно, что допускается в ссылке ($url), любой текст или цифры

```
$url2 = "youtube.com/watch?v=";
preg_match("#^(https?://)?youtube.com/watch\?v=.*$#", $url2);
```

Данный код почему то выдает true даже на $url2, хотя так не должно быть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Данный код почему то выдает true даже на $url2, хотя так не должно быть*

Это происходит из-за минимальности квантификатора `*`, который делает дальнейшее совпадение в подстроке не обязательным, даже если совпадение есть. Замените `*` на `+`, и шаблон будет учитывать подстроку после `v=`:

```
$str = 'youtube.com/watch?v=';

$patt = '~^(?:https?://)?youtube.com/watch\?v=.+$~';

var_dump( (bool) preg_match($patt, $str) );
```

Результат:

```
boolean false
```